# pod set up is failing Mac OS Sierra

Tags: xcode, git, macos, cocoapods, homebrew

After I got new Macbook pro I tried to install cocoapods

but I am unable to setup pod.
please see the below image.

[image: pod set up failure]

I have updated brew, and updated git.

Even I tried to set git global http post buffer. 
nothing is solved my problem.
I tried with the following command

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Cocoapods bug report](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6192), it's a problem with your connection to GitHub, where your connection can be broken by your firewall, VPN or antivirus configurations.

They suggest using solutions [found here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/git-clone-fails-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200-693897332.html) (try the ones for LINUX), but my first suggestion is to simply turn off your firewall or VPN while you are setting up your Cocoapods.